# Amazon S3 Bucket Upload all files empty

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have installed amazon aws SDK for php. I am trying to upload a file off of the server into the s3 bucket. So here is the current flow, user uploads a picture, we save it, then we run a cropping script. Then we have the image all cropped and ready to go saved on our ec2 instance. I then want to transfer this file to the s3 bucket so I can erase it from the server. My issue is the upload process "works" but all the files that get uploaded are 20-50 bytes in size. Here is my code below

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
'Bucket'     => 'images',
'ACL'           => 'public-read',
'Key'        => '/avatars/myImage.jpg',
'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
'Body' => $imgUrl
));
```

This creates a file on my amazon s3 bucket, of the right type, location and permissions. But the file is always 20-50bytes aka empty. Any idea what could be causing this? $imgUrl is the path to the file.

Comment: What does the file look like on the server before uploading?

Comment: If I manually go to the file on the ec2 server, at time of upload or after it looks totally normal, and is not 20-50 bytes.

Comment: Try this: **`'Body'   => fopen($pathToFile, 'r+')`**. From the documentation: `Pass a string containing the body, a handle returned by fopen, or a Guzzle\Http\EntityBodyInterface object`

Comment: ahah!!!! it worked! thanks so much, you should post as answer.

Comment: @CalvinMoss, Glad it worked. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @CalvinMoss, As your issue has been resolved, could you accept my answer so that others know that this thread is resolved. Also, it gives me [credit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/244809) for my time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This: **`'Body'   => fopen($pathToFile, 'r+')`**

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#)

> Pass a string containing the body, a handle returned by fopen, or a
>   Guzzle\Http\EntityBodyInterface object

Comment: You can see an example of this [on the SDK's README](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php#upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3) and [in the SDK's User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-objects).